# Concatenating strings in OCaml

Tags: string, recursion, concatenation, ocaml

I'm writing a recursive OCaml function that concatenates strings in a string list joined by a separator without placing a separator on the last item but I'm running into some issues. I know that there's a string.concat function, but I prefer not to use that so as to learn how OCaml performs these operations under the hood. Here is what I have so far:

`

```
let rec join (separator: string) (l: string list) : string =
  begin match l with 
  | []-> ""
  | [hd]-> hd
  | hd::tl-> if hd != "" then hd^separator else ..... 
  end
```

`

I'm using pattern matching to match the string list l and cover three cases: case 1 return nothing if the string list is empty; case 2 returns just the head if the list contains no tail. Tail three performs the concatenation while simultaneously recursing on the join function to concatenate the other items in the list with the string separator in between. However I'm unsure as to how to implement this while simultaneously recursing on the tail and paying respect to OCaml's need for every statement to evaluate to an expression. This is a trivial problem in C or Java, but can't figure this out and any help or pointers is appreciated

Answer (score 8):

For what it's worth, I don't see why you want to behave differently when the head of the list is an empty string.

Here's what the built-in string concatenation function does for that case:

```
# String.concat "," [""; "yes"];;
- : string = ",yes"
```

This looks pretty reasonable to me, and it's the same behavior as for a non-"" list head.

Assuming you do want to do something different when the head is "", your code doesn't do any recursion for that case. So the entire output will be just one separator.

If you just go ahead and write the `else` part with two uses of the `^` operator and a recursive call to `join` you should find that the code is just as easy in OCaml as in C or Java.

Comment: But how is it possible to make a recursive call and perform a concatenation operation in the same else block without OCaml throwing a type error?

Comment: What did you try? A recursive call like this `join separator tl` is a legitimate call, and it returns a value of type string (by recursion hypothesis).

Comment: I actually see why that sort of recursive call would work, given that join takes in two parameters.

Comment: You might get more useful answers if you show your code that doesn't work and explain how it fails.

Answer (score 5):

A naive `join` is straightforward:

```
let rec join separator = function
  | [] -> ""
  | [str] -> str
  | ""::strs -> join separator strs
  | str::strs -> str ^ separator ^ join separator strs
```

This avoids spurious commas, which is what it seems you are trying to do. Note that this is *not* the behaviour of `List.concat`.

While a reasonable programming exercise for somebody new to OCaml, this version of `join` is not acceptable: it does work quadratic in the sum of the lengths of the strings. A linear time implementation might use `Buffer`:

```
let join separator = function
  | [] -> ""
  | [str] -> str
  | str::strs ->
    let buf = Buffer.create 0 in
    Buffer.add_string buf str;
    List.iter (function
        | "" -> ()
        | s ->
          Buffer.add_string buf separator;
          Buffer.add_string buf s)
      strs;
    Buffer.contents buf
```

Which is uglier, but has acceptable time complexity.